# Nagios check_http on custom url

Tags: macros, nagios, opsview

I am trying to set up some monitoring for my host. I know that I can access it via the macro `$HOSTADDRESS$`, but how can I actually append the correct string to it? The `$HOSTADDRESS$` won't return anything on just the root (so nothing on `/`), but I want it rather to check on `/health-check`. Is it possible to append the `/health-check` to `$HOSTADDRESS$` somehow?

Using Opsview 6, which is based on Nagios.

Comment: Maybe this should help https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/macros.html
 Look at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the change to check_http in your service description

```
check_http --help
...
 -u, --url=PATH
    URL to GET or POST (default: /)
...

check_command   check_http!--url=/health-check
```